# Spring MVC как добавить изображение и вывести из mysql

Tags: java, mysql, spring, файлы, mvc

Пытаюсь разобраться как добавлять изображения из формы и потом выводить их на основной странице.

У меня есть модель для файла

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "item")
public class Items {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long item_name;
    private String title;
    private String price;
    private String min_desc;
    @Lob
    private byte[] image;

    public Items() { }

    public Items(String title, String price, String min_desc, byte[] image) {
        this.title = title;
        this.price = price;
        this.min_desc = min_desc;
        this.image = image;
    }
```

И есть добавление

```
public String add(@RequestParam String title, @RequestParam String price, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,@RequestParam String desc, Model model) throws IOException {
            itemRepo.save(new Items(title,price,desc,file.getBytes()));
            return "index";
        }
```

Но таким способом корректно не работает, не понимаю как сделать правильно вывод и ввод изображения!!!

Comment: Поясните, что значит "корректно не работает".

Comment: Здравствуйте, в смысле вообще

Comment: @Никита-Долински проверьте в debug доходят ли данные до entity, и что пишет при попытке сохранить в базу?

Comment: @Алексей Осецкий получилось, а как вывести само изображение если оно в blob

Comment: @Никита-Долински или срузу изображение на экран выводить до того как вы в базу сохранили, а потом уже в базу сохранять, либо сначала сохранять в базу, потом вытаскивать от туда blob, преобразоывать его обратно по байтам с возвращать обратно

Comment: @Алексей Осецкий, Получается, что я делаю, что-то наподобие админ панели, мне нужно загружать, например, товар в базу данных через админ панель и чтобы потом она автоматом выводилась на основном сайте, если можете покажите пожалуйста как преобразовывать его по байтам и выводить на сайт

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Преобразование Blob в массив байт

```
blob.getBytes(1, (int) blob.length());
```

2. Controller

```
@GetMapping("/img/{id}")
public void getImage(@PathVariable("id") Long id, HttpServletResponse response) {
        imageService.writeImageToRespose(id, response);
}
```

3. Service

```
public void writeImageToRespose(Long id, HttpServletResponse response) {
        //store image in browser cache
        response.setContentType("image/jpeg, image/jpg, image/png, image/gif");
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=2628000");

        //obtaining bytes from DB
        byte[] imageData = someEntityDao.getPhotoById(id);

        //Some conversion
        //Maybe to base64 string or something else
        //Pay attention to encoding (UTF-8, etc)
       
        //write result to http response
        try (OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream()) {
            out.write(convertedStringBytes);
        }
}
```

4. Отобаржение в jsp

```
th:src="*{'/img/' + entity.id}"
```

Код не проверял

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Если ответ полезен, то лучше нажать стелочку вверх на против него, если является ответом, то выбрать как ответ. Вот [правила оформления ответов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: я бы поставил но, мой голос не учитывается